# On click loading spinner should only appear on the clicked button

Tags: html, css, reactjs

When I click a button, the spinning svg shows on all the buttons, but I want only the clicked button to show the spinning SVG.

[link for the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-dg1mj6?file=src%2FApp.jsx) 
[button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNcaE.jpg)
[after clicking (problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otONW.jpg)

I tried giving unique ID to the buttons, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To ensure that only the clicked button shows the spinning SVG, you can track the clicked button's index and use it to determine which button should show the spinner. Here's an updated version of your component:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const buttonArray = ['btn-1', 'btn-2', 'btn-3', 'btn-4', 'btn-5'];

function App() {
  const [clickedIndex, setClickedIndex] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = (index) => {
    setClickedIndex(index);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setClickedIndex(null);
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        {buttonArray.map((btn, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={btn} className="field">
              <button onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>
                {clickedIndex !== index ? (
                  'click-btn'
                ) : (
                  <img src="spinner_green.svg" alt={btn} />
                )}
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In my code, clickedIndex state is used to track the index of the button that was clicked. When a button is clicked, its index is stored in clickedIndex, and the clickedIndex is used to determine whether to show the spinning SVG for that button. The spinner is only shown for the button with the matching index.